# How to structure Web API code such that the link will support api/values/{id}/name

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I am new to learning Web API code in C# and was wondering how to create the following link that gets the name for a specific value ID.

The provided code below does not work as I want it to with the "/name" behind it.

```
// GET api/values/{id}/name
public string Get(int id)
{
    return getNameValue(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom route like:

```
[Route("{id:int}/name")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return getNameValue(id);
}
```

### **Update:**

In WebApiConfig, modify register method to have custom routes

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id:int}/name",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there another way without using a custom route?

Comment: you can modify WebAPIConfig to have custom route

Comment: Just a follow up question to your edit; Wouldn't modifying the WebApiConfig also have effects on other controllers as well? What if I only want one controller to have that link property and the rest to have the regular link?

Comment: Instead of adding genric route you can add named route for that controller only

Comment: HINT: value inside `{ }` is generic, replace that with name of controller, it will be for that controller only

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use attribute routing without defining the route in route config.
Add the below code which enable attribute routing(This feature is only applicable to Web API 2).
[Attribute routing Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //**enabling attribute routing here.**

    // Convention-based routing.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

then you can make use of:

```
[Route("{id:int}/name")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return getNameValue(id);
}
```